# Check if navigator.app.backHistory exist

Tags: android, angularjs, ionic-framework, mobile-application

I have an Ionic v1 App and in the Android version I am trying to override the default hardware back button. Instead of the hardware back button closing the app, I want it to go to the previous page in the app. This is my code in the run block:

```
$ionicPlatform.registerBackButtonAction(function () {
            if (typeof(navigator) != 'undefined' && typeof(navigator.app) != 'undefined' && typeof(navigator.app.backHistory) == 'function')
            {
              navigator.app.backHistory();
            }
            else {
              navigator.app.exitApp();
            }
         }, 100);
```

You can see that the hardware back button navigates the user to the previous state in my app itself instead of closing the App. But what I want to do is, if there are no more stacks in the `navigator.app.backHistory()`, I want it to exit the App. How can I do that? How can I check if there are any more history states in `navigator.app.backHistory()`?

Answer (score 1):

Instead you should check if view is your home page:

```
            if($state.current.name === "bookevent.home"){
              navigator.app.exitApp();
            }
            else {
                navigator.app.backHistory();
            }
```

otherwise, you can also handle complex situations with ($ionicHistory,$state):

```
    if ($state.current.name === "bookevent.detail" || $state.current.name === "bookevent.online" || $state.current.name === "bookevent.offline") {
        navigator.app.backHistory();
    }
    else if($state.current.name === "bookevent.home"){
      navigator.app.exitApp();
    }
    else {
        $ionicHistory.nextViewOptions({
            disableBack: true
        });
        $state.go("bookevent.home");
    }
```